# the Comparison Functions in C++

Tags: c++, stl

I am currently learning STL in C++. And I was looking at references on a program I'm coding. It is using priority queue with a custom object.

```
struct Foo
{
    std::list<int> path;
    int cost;
    bool operator>(const Foo& rhs) const
    {
        return cost > rhs.cost;
    }
};
```

---

```
class mycomparison
{
public:
    bool operator() (Foo p1, Foo p2) const{
        return (p1>p2);
    }
};
```

---

```
priority_queue<Foo,vector<Foo>,mycomparison> myPQ;
```

The objects in the priority queue is prioritized for ones with lower cost. I know that you are able to define custom comparators. But I'm not sure why there is an overloaded operator in the struct, and a custom one in class mycomparison, which is used in the priority queue. If I removed the overloaded operator in the struct, it refuses to run.

If someone would please explain to me the use of both code, the relations, how it affects one another, it would be much appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: Follow the logic.  What does `mycomparison::operator()` do?  What does it require to work?

Comment: All you need is a less-than operator`<` for your type. If then implement that to mean that the right-hand-side is "larger" than the object is up to you.

Comment: `p1>p2` calls `Foo`s overload for `operator<`. What exactly dont you understand about the code?

Comment: btw you dont need `mycomparison`, as the comparison defaults to `std::less<Foo>` that also calls `Foo`s `operator<`

Comment: Before I asked this question, I did'nt understand what you just explained, @user46305818

Comment: @user463035818 Except that `Foo` has a `operator>` and not `operator<`.

Comment: So it'd be alright to call std:: greater <Foo> ? With > overloaded operator?

Comment: @user478905 Correct.

Comment: yes, but it is more common to implement `operator<`, at least most algorithms I know use `<` and dont care about the existence of a `>`

Answer (score 4):

`std::priority_queue` uses `std::less<T>` as the default comparator.

If and when that is not appropriate, as in your case, you have to define a custom comparator or use another comparator that is appropriate for your need.

The implementation details of the `operator()` function of the comparator is entirely up to you.

Do you need the `operator>` function in `Foo`? Certainly not. You could have used:

```
class mycomparison
{
  public:
    bool operator() (Foo p1, Foo p2) const{
        return (p1.cost > p2.cost);
    }
};
```

That could have obviated the need to implement `Foo::operator>`.

However, using `return (p1 > p2)` keeps the abstractions in the right place. The details of what `p1 > p2` means is best left up to `Foo`.

BTW, you could have used:

```
std::priority_queue<Foo, std::vector<Foo>, std::greater<Foo>> myPQ;
```

That would have made `mycomparison` unnecessary.